# Оптимизация алгоритма вычисления расстояний между ячейками в частицах

Tags: c, алгоритм, c++

Есть вопрос оптимизации алгоритма.

[image]

Это своеобразное представление кристалической решётки. Прямоугольные параллелепипеды (частицы), состоящие из точек - ячеек (27 штук), образуют кристалличекую решётку. Задаются расстояния по x,y,z между частицами (a,b,c) и между ячейками(a',b',c') в частице. Необходимо раcсчитать расстояние между каждыми двумя ячейками, не входящими в одну частицу.

Реализовал расчёт расстояний через длину вектора, поскольку, поместив начало координат в какую-либо ячейку, можно вычислить координаты всех ячеек. Но расчёт расстояний по всем ячейкам занимает очень много времени для образца размером, например, `10*100*100` частиц. Просьба предложить алгоритм, позволяющий производить рассчёт более эффективно.

Кусок кода для рассчёта расстояний с учётом следующего алгоритма:

1. Расчёт расстояний внутри 1 слоя ZY
2. Расчёт расстояний от каждой ячейки внутри слоя до каждой ячейки в следующем слое ZY.
3. И так далее до последнего слоя.
4. Потом необходимо сделать комбинацию расстояний, чтобы вычисить полные расстояния.

```
// В плоскости YZ вычисляем энергию зваимодействия ячеек в одном слое
for (int i = 0; i < 27 * Y * Z; i++) {
    if (i % 27 == 0) {
        part_num++;
    }

for (int j = 0; j < (part_num - 1) * 27; j++) {
        distance =
            sqrt(pow((x_vect.at(i) - x_vect.at(j)), 2) +
            pow((y_vect.at(i) - y_vect.at(j)), 2) + 
            pow((z_vect.at(i) - z_vect.at(j)), 2));
    }

for (int j = (part_num) * 27; j < 27 * Y * Z; j++) {
        distance =
            sqrt(pow((x_vect.at(i) - x_vect.at(j)), 2) +
            pow((y_vect.at(i) - y_vect.at(j)), 2) + 
            pow((z_vect.at(i) - z_vect.at(j)), 2));
    }
}

// Выбираем слой
for (int layer = 1; layer < X; layer++) {
    // В плоскости YZ вычисляем энергию зваимодействия ячеек в разных слоях
    for (int i = 0; i < 27 * Y * Z; i++) {
        for (int j = 27 * Y * Z * layer; j < Z * Y * 27 * (layer + 1); j++) {
            distance =
                sqrt(pow((x_vect.at(i) - x_vect.at(j)), 2) +
                pow((y_vect.at(i) - y_vect.at(j)), 2) + 
                pow((z_vect.at(i) - z_vect.at(j)), 2));
        }
    }

cout << "Layer: " << layer << endl;
}
```

Прошу помочь с алгоритмом.

Comment: Мои предположения: Ну, можно положить, что если расстояние между частицами заметно превышает размер частицы, то расстояние между ячейками в разных удалённых частицах примерно равно расстоянию между частицами =)
Если там действителен принцип местного влияния, то совсем дальние вообще можно не считать...

Так как решётка периодична по всем координатам, то расстояния между частицами можно представить в виде таблицы, где координаты - относительные номера слоёв?

Comment: По условию задачи невозможно пренебречь ячейками в дальних частицах. Модель точная, поскольку именно в саму модель вложена апроксимация на другие физические условия)

Comment: А расчёт расстояний происходит каждый раз по всем временам моделирования? Тогда я голосую за таблицу =)

Comment: Рассматривается статический случай с фиксированными расстояниями. Если интересно, то я пытаюсь реализовать алгоритм, который описан в следующей статье:
http://journals.ioffe.ru/ftt/2010/03/page-572.html.ru
Это журнал Физика твердого тела.

Comment: Прочитаю, это интересно =)

Я только не понял - в модели они псевдоспины рандомом назначают?

Comment: Наверное, для начала, можно вытащить вычисление функций x_vect.at(i), y_vect.at(i), z_vect.at(i) (я правильно понимаю, что это 'чистые' функции ?) из циклов по j. А вообще из приведенного кода не понятно, что требуется вычислить. distance ? Так она постоянно переписывается.

Comment: Как опсино в статье, энергия взаимодействия вычисляется через расстояния. Т.е. основной этам - это вычисление расстояний. После вычисления каждого расстояния по нему вычисляется энернгия, далее по следующему расстоянию опять же вычисляется энергия и они суммируются. Поэтому, применяя функцию вычисления энергии(которая ещё в коде не реализована) к каждому вычисленному расстоянию, будет получено решение задачи.

Comment: Псевдоспины , в соответствии с моделью Изинга, заюдся слкчайным образом, но в соответствии с каким-либо распределением случайных чисел(например, Гиббса). Но если посмотреть на переход из (15) в (16) в статье, то становится очевидно, что произведение 2х псевдоспинов принимается равным -1

Comment: Для avp
Для упрощения сохранения результатов вычисления координат ячеек,  я использовал std::vector. Создал 3 вектора для координат x,y,z и в них подряд записывал значения для каждой следующей ячейки. Получить номер частицы, в которой находится ячейка можно делением номера ячейки на 27, т.к. в частице 27 ячеек

Answer (score 2):

Дистанция между двумя ячейками может быть представлена как

```
d(i,p,j,q,k,r) = 
    sqrt( (i*a+p*a')*(i*a+p*a') + (j*b+q*b')*(j*b+q*b') + (k*c+r*c')*(kc+rc')),
```

где

- `-n < i < n`,  `-2<= p<= 2`,  `-n < j < n`,  `-2<= q<= 2`,  `-n < k < n`,  `-2<= r<= 2`;
- `i`, `j`, `k` - разность индексов двух частиц по `x`, `y`, `z` соответственно;
- `p`, `q`, `r` - разность индексов ячеек двух частиц по `x`, `y`, `z` соответственно при условии совмещения центров частиц

При этом очевидно выполняются условия

```
d(i,p,j,q,k,r) = 
    d(i,p,k,r,j,q) = 
        d(j,q,i,p,k,r) = 
            d(j,q,k,r,i,p) =
                d(k,r,i,p,j,q) = 
                    d(k,r,j,q,i,p)

d(-i,p,j,q,k,r) = d(i,-p,j,q,k,r)
d(i,p,-j,q,k,r) = d(i,p,j,-q,k,r)
d(i,p,j,q,-k,r) = d(i,p,j,q,k,-r)
```

Последнее означает, что `i`, `j`, `k` можно всегда считать неотрицательными в диапазоне от `0` до `n-1`.

Таким образом, для случая решетки `n*n*n` частиц число всевозможных расстояний

```
d(i,p,j,q,k,r) = m*(m-1)*(m-2)/6 + m*(m-1) + m = m*(m*m +3*m +2)/6,
```

где `m = 5*n`. Если `n=50` достаточно вычислить и сохранить `2635500` различных расстояний. И вместо расчёта расстояний просто в зависимости от разности индексов ячеек в переменных `i`, `j`, `k`, `p`, `q`, `r` брать нужное расстояние. Правда потребуется определенной порядок хранения `d(i,p,j,q,k,r)` и обращения к ним. Если же не заморачиваться с этим, то можно хранить все `m*mm` расстояний, т.е. при `n=50` это `15625000` чисел, что также терпимо при современных объемах оперативной памяти.

Comment: Раз данные часто повторяются, то возможно автору темы стоит посмотреть в сторону алгоритмов динамического программирования. Похоже на задачу динамического программирования (есть хорошая книжка по алгоритмам, Кормена и Лейзерсона, с соответствующим разделом, там разбирают ряд задач с похожими свойствами). Вряд ли вам тут напишут готовое решение - это довольно трудоемко. Но вот в такую сторону можно поглядеть...

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, приведённая модель вряд ли оптимизируется без дальнейших физических аппроксимаций. Время обработки (и объём ответа) можно оценить как `(27*X*Y*Z)^2` (более строго, `Theta((X*Y*Z)^2)`). Рассмотрим образец 10x100x100 (`X*Y*Z = 10^5`). Тогда объём ответа (т.е. сумма занимаемой памяти по всем distance), считая в single-precision, будет примерно 29160 ГБ. Понятно, что одновременно эти данные нужны не будут, так что проблема только во времени их обработки. На достаточно быстром сервере/кластере это можно сделать за десяток минут (или меньше), плюс задача хорошо распараллеливается. Вопрос в том, есть ли у Вас доступ к таким мощностям, или Вы можете себе позволить дальнейшие аппроксимации, уменьшив количество значений distance, входящих в ответ.

Comment: Проблема заключается во времени расчёта и неумении работать с, например, MPI. Скорее всего, придётся ограничится более скромными размерами образца.Но всё равно, хочется найти более легкое математическое решение поставленной задачи. Двигаюсь в этом направлении.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, не нужно рассчитывать все расстояния в данной модели, т.к. они будут дублироваться. Например, диагональных векторов будет 4.

Comment: Приходится рассчитывать каждое расстояние, поскольку далее необходимо производить расчёты на основе расстояния. Есть возможность не считать все, поскольку они действительно повторяются, но, тогда все расстояния приходится сохранять, а это размен памяти на скорость

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае уместно определить минимальное расстояние на котором взаимодействие частиц приравнивается к нулю.т.к.
"При больших расстояниях между
частицами температура перехода близка к температуре
фазового перехода в изолированной частице, смещен-
ной за счет размерных эффектов"
В этом случае можно посчитать минимальное(27) и максимальное количество частиц, что даст и ответ на вопрос нужно ли оптимизировать алгоритм.

Comment: "При больших расстояниях между частицами температура перехода близка к температуре фазового перехода в изолированной частице, смещенной за счет размерных эффектов"

На мой взгляд, это и есть вывод из проделанных расчётов, т.е. результат моделирования.

Answer (score 0):

Если решетка состоит из строго ортогональных отрезков (как на рисунке) и если длина отрезков фиксирована, то, если разумно пронумеровать ячейки, можно существенно оптимизировать. Тогда заранее считаете стандартные длины отрезков и пишите отображение

> (индексЯчейки, индексЯчейки) --> расстояние

к которому обращаетесь по мере надобности (оно будет нужное количество раз суммировать фиксированные заранее рассчитанные длины).

P.S. Подозреваю, что на рисунке всё сильно упрощено.

Comment: На данный момент программа реализует самый топорный способ расчёта - (расстояние между каждой ячейкой с каждой)/2, т.к. расстояние от точки а до б = от б до а.
Расчёт образца 20*20*20 частиц по 27 ячеек занимает 16 минут. А хотелось бы рассчитать 50*50*15 частиц за приемлимое время, т.к. объём вычисление при увеличении размера растёт нелинейно

Answer (score 0):

Допустим есть 3х3х20 частиц по 27 ячеек.

- Вычисляем расстояния первого слоя.
- Потом от первого до второго.
- От первого к третьему (от второго к третьему = от  первого к второму).
- От первого к четвертому (от второго к четвертому = от первого к третьему, от третьего к четвертому = от первого до второго).
- ...

Эффект турбо-топора. =)

Comment: Ага, это я тоже придумал. Но там получается, что надо хранить все эти расстояния.

Comment: а что тогда вы храните???

Comment: Я вычисляю каждое расстояние, потом по нему вычисляю энергию. И эти энергии просто складываю. И не приходится сохранять расстояния.

В случае расчёта по слоям, придётся делать столько массивов (векторов) для расстояний, сколько слоёв. А потом муторно по индексу вычислять каждую частицу.

Comment: Могу скинуть код получившейся программы на мыло.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам нужно сложить энергии, зависящие только от расстояния, то даже собственно расстояние  можно подсчитать потом вместе с энергией. Просто в цикле перебора всех ячеек
в ячейке памяти, соответствующей `d(i,p,j,q,k,r)` подсчитывать количество раз, когда был востребован индекс `i,p,j,q,k,r` и затем уже, когда весь цикл по парам ячеек будет пройден, подсчитать и дистанцию и элементарную энергию, соответствующую индексу `i,p,j,q,k,r` умножив на количество раз, когда этот индекс был востребован.

**Добавление.**

Если Вам нужно сложить энергии, зависящие только от расстояния между ячейками, то послойный вариант также хорош, так как в этом случае общая энергия

```
E = n*E(0) + (n-1)*E(1) + (n-2)*E(2) +...+E(n-1)
```

где `E(k)` - вклад в энергию от слоев, отстоящих на k единиц шага решетки между частицами по соответствующей координате.

Comment: Спасибо всем огромное за участие! Уточняю задачу: 
Необходимо вычислить энергию взаимодействия каждой ячейки с другой ячейкой. При этом энергия взаимодействия делится на энергию взаимодействия ячеек внутри частицы и на взаимодействие ячеек в разных частицах. Энергия - функция расстояния + в энергии есть в качестве слагаемого проекция вектора расстояния на ось z (это разность координат начала и конца вектора на оси z). Для каждой ячейки вычисляется сумма взаимодействий со всеми другими ячейками вне частицы и сумма внутри частицы. Сумму взаимодействий внутри частицы достаточно расчитать 1 раз.

Comment: После расчётов берётся частица и для неё вычисляется полная энергия = сумме суммы энергий взаимодействия с другими ячейками вне частицы + сумма взаимодействия энергии внутри частицы.